# Custom Button redirecting to a VF page using URL as a content souce with validation

Tags: visualforce, community, validation, dynamic-visualforce, leads

I'm facing an issue in redirecting to a VisualForce page using a custom button in which the button content source need to be an URL which need to validate a particular filed is null or not. If yes,it should redirect to a VF page else it should redirect to a different page.

Formula:
**{!IF(  ISBLANK( Lead.Company )  , "/apex/page1", "/apex/page2")}**

I tried using different scenarios but facing this error:

**https://na30.salesforce.com/servlet/%2Fapex%2Fpage2**

Please help me finding a way to solve this.

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Have you tried with a full URL?

Comment: Yes, I did but it's redirecting to this link
** URL:https://na30.salesforce.com/servlet/https%3A%2F%2Fc.na30.visual.force.com%2Fapex%2Fpage2 **

Comment: Which object did you create the button?

Comment: I need to create a custom button on lead object. When ever the user hits the button it should rout to VF pages(Page1,Page2) with some validation on a filed were to redirect the page.